# Working with Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a Rad combo box and a 2 RadGrids - grvUser and grvRole

grvUser RadGrid is as follows...

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grvUser" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"  Skin="skn_RadGrid" SkinsDir="|CurrentTheme|/" SkinsPath="|CurrentTheme|/"
            OnItemCreated="grvUser_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="grvUser_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="grvUser_ItemDataBound" OnNeedDataSource="grvUser_NeedDataSource" GroupHeaderItemStyle-CssClass="rgGroupPanel">
            <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed" OverrideDataSourceControlSorting="true" NoMasterRecordsText ="No Records Found, Please Refine Search To Display "> 
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" DataField="UserId"
                        UniqueName="UserId" HeaderText="User Id" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" FilterControlWidth="70px"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" DataField="UserName" AllowFiltering="true" ShowFilterIcon="true"
                        UniqueName="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" FilterControlWidth="70px"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

grvRole RadGrid is as follows...

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grvRole" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"  Skin="skn_RadGrid" SkinsDir="|CurrentTheme|/" SkinsPath="|CurrentTheme|/"
            OnItemCreated="grvRole_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="grvRole_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="grvRole_ItemDataBound" OnNeedDataSource="grvRole_NeedDataSource" GroupHeaderItemStyle-CssClass="rgGroupPanel">
            <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed" OverrideDataSourceControlSorting="true" NoMasterRecordsText ="No Records Found, Please Refine Search To Display "> 
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" DataField="RoleId"
                        UniqueName="RoleId" HeaderText="Role Id" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" FilterControlWidth="70px"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" DataField="RoleName" AllowFiltering="true" ShowFilterIcon="true"
                        UniqueName="RoleName" HeaderText="Role Name" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" FilterControlWidth="70px"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
             </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Code for RadComboBox is as follows...

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlType" runat="server" DataValueField="Description"
                        DataTextField="Description" Text="(Select)" AllowCustomText="True" Width="200px"
                        OnClientDropDownClosed="onDropDownClosing1"  Skin="Default">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div onclick="StopPropagation(event)" class="combo-item-template" onmousemove="">
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" onclick="onStatusChecked(this)" />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" AssociatedControlID="chk1">
                              <%# Eval("Description")%>
                                </asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChckAll" Text="(Check All)" runat="server" OnClick="checkAllStatus(this)" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

The `ddlType` RadComboBox contains 2 values. 1 is User and 2 is Role. By default "User" is selected and such that `grvUser` will be  displayed. If the user selects Role, then we need to display `grvRole` defined in the aspx page.

How can I fire onchange event for RadComboBox and display proper RadGrid either User or Role?

**UPDATE**

Implementation in jQuery is Ok for me.

Comment: Hi, What is the question ? What is the issue ? RadComboBox has few event you can try `OnItemChecked` `OnSelectedIndexChanged`. To display proper grid just hide one and show the other.

Comment: On change of combo box, I need to display proper grid. Could you please provide me an example.

Comment: Pretty sure you try those but you didnt use the doc to know why it wasn't firing .. Autopostback was the key http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/server-side-programming/selectedindexchanged Writen in RED is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whatever is well conceived is clearly said, And the words  to say it
>   flow with ease.

### How to: Show / hide control based on a RadComboBox Value ?

First let's declare a simple RadComboBox with 3 In-line Items :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" >
    <Items>   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="ALL" />   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="grvUser" />   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="grvRole" /> 
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

#### 1/. We now need an event that will be fire every time user choose a "Value".

`OnSelectedIndexChanged` Will do the trick. 
As You talk about a jQuery implementation, here is the documentation RadComboBox event :

- [Server-side event](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/server-side-programming/events)
- [Client-side event](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/overview)

> **NOTE:** The *SelectedIndexChanged* , *TextChanged* and *OnCheckAllCheck* events *do not fire* unless you set the *AutoPostBack property to True* .

#### 2/.Add the correct event, and some label.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" autopostback="True"
                     OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
    <Items>   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="ALL" />   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="grvUser" />   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="grvRole" /> 
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="My Control 1(grvUser)" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="My Control 2(grvRole)" />
```

#### 3/. Lets hide them in code behind

```
protected void RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Text=="ALL")
    { 
        Label1.Visible = true; 
        Label2.Visible = true; 
    }
    else if (e.Text == "grvUser")            
    {
        Label1.Visible=true; 
        Label2.Visible=false;
    }
    else if (e.Text == "grvRole")
    { 
        Label1.Visible = false; 
        Label2.Visible = true; 
    }
}
```

**That was a Client-side solution.**

Answer (score 1):

Use this to show field-
var agtype = $telerik.$(atCell).text().trim();

if(agtype == ""Guaranty""){{
       var masterTableView = sender.get_masterTableView();
       var columnIndex = masterTableView.getColumnByUniqueName(""Amount"").get_element().cellIndex;
       masterTableView.showColumn(columnIndex);
}}